# what is the way to handle dual boot for lenovo G50-70

Tags: windows-10, laptop, multi-boot, lenovo-laptop

on windows 10. install dual boot ubuntu 16.04 LTS. the first month the system is working properly. after using ubuntu for a while, when restart or shutdown/restart the computer, the computer is in the black screen and won't load to the bios and access the operating system. 
any way to handle the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is covered thoroughly on ask Ubuntu and the solution could be one of many options. I suggest you read the following article covering most of the problems:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it